# RMI client timeout when server is down or wrong adress is provided

Tags: sockets, rmi, ping

Long story short, i want to specify to the client a timeout when invoking the lookup method. The reason i'm doing this is that my application should give the user the possibility to specify the adress and the port of the remote server himself. So in case of wrong config (e.g address like 124.0.0.1), the client will have to wait for a hole minute for tha app to respond.
I've tried the following properties but in vain :

1. -Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.handshakeTimeout=10000
2. -Dsun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout=10000
3. -Dsun.rmi.transport.proxy.connectTimeout=10000

The only solution that  worked for me is to implement the RMIClientSocketFactory, create a socket inside the createSocket method and specify the time out for this socket like this

```
new RMIClientSocketFactory() {

                @Override
                public Socket createSocket(String host, int port)
                        throws IOException {
                    Socket socket = new Socket();
                    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), 10000);
                    return socket;
                }
            };
```

But i don't want to use this solution cause it is ugly and risked.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: it's like never there, with it or without it the time out is always the same 1min 03 sec